# Unable to load .html URL in webview

Tags: android

I am getting.html url from response I want to set that url into webview and want open that url into browser but I am unable to do this I am getting submit button when loading that url but not getting next page of it how I do this?

I am getting this url from response

private String url = "https://post.wealthstreet.in/Response/57.html";

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private WebView webView;
    private String url = "https://post.wealthstreet.in/Response/57.html";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.loadUrl(url);


    }
 private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                WebView view, String url) {
            return (false);
        }
    }
```

How I do this ,I am unable to load this url what is the issue?isany method 
  required for this? when loading this url getting submit button in browser 
  when I am loading this url ,submit button automatic redirectmain page but 
  not working in webview..........